# Having problems installing ImageMagick on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, imagemagick

Trying to install imagemagick since 1.5 hrs but with no luck.

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick php5-imagick
```

But nothing is happening. I tried to cross check with

```
if (!extension_loaded('imagick'))
    echo 'imagick not installed';
```

And it is returning the message, means not loaded. I have also tried to find `imagick.so` file path but that also couldn't find.

There is one `imagemagick` folder including some `xml` files. So my question is that is it all files of Imagemagick or something I am missing. Also do I need to add `imagick.so` in `php.ini` file?

Very confused, please help me

Comment: Is there no output at all when you run `sudo apt-get install imagemagick`? And what's the output of `ls /usr/lib/php5/20121212/imagick.so`?

Comment: Try to install imagick with pear.

Comment: I got return value of the same path. So what I have to do now? Should I add this path to php.ini?

Comment: Okay so I have added extension to `php.ini` on this path `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and its loaded now. Checked with `phpinfo()` and I can see its there. Only one question. Did I edit right `php.ini`? because I have seen some post saying there are many `php.ini` so `cli` module should be added in `/cli/php.ini` but I have added in above path. So it is okay?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try this:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
sudo php5enmod imagick
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me...

The first installs ImageMagick on the server.  The second installs the PHP 5 ImageMagick module.  The third restarts your Apache configuration.

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
sudo service apache2 graceful
```

**UPDATE:** Looking at your original question, you may need to simply run the last command to reload the Apache config file (or fully restart Apache).

Answer (score 0):

I did the following steps worked for me:

```
php -v

PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17 (cli) (built: May 19 2016 19:08:09)


$sudo apt-get install php5 php5-common gcc
$sudo apt-get install imagemagick
$sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
$php -m | grep imagick
$service apache2 restart
```

Check the status by executing:

> ```
> php -m | grep imagick
> imagick
> ```